# StackOverflow error when opening file in IE7-8

Tags: html, wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, stack-overflow

I'm getting a Stack Overflow error when I'm trying to open files on my website using IE7-8 (Note: It takes a "true" IE7-8, the emulated version from IE11 doesn't do it)

It doesn't do it with all the files, and the problem seems unrelated to the file size or type. (The problem occurs when opening a 308kb PDF and a 31 MB PPT, but doesn't occur on a 844KB and 90KB PDF later in the page)

The website is a classic WP3.8 with a custom theme (coded on WP standards, without any plugins that change WP drastically).

So well, here's the question. What could provoke a simple link to a PDF to return a StackOverflow error?

PS: Sadly, I cannot give you access to the page where the error happens. It's a private page for my client. But here is the ouputted code that provokes the error

```
<a href="http://www.example.ca/[pathToPDF].pdf" target="_blank"><img class="aligncenter  wp-image-1674" alt="cahier[1]" src="http://www.example.ca/[pathToAnImage].jpg" width="112" height="90">CAHIER</a>
```

Comment: well, the problem would be located into the pdf reader plugin as I see it... nothing you can control actually, but hard to track.

Comment: The VM we run to test IE7-8 has no PDF reader of any sort. Only IE7 installed

Comment: Do you have doctype set for HTML5 or XHTML1.0 Transitional? It might be entering quirks mode, which I think will freak out with multiple classes per element.

Comment: Could be it, but still seems weird that it doesn't do it for every File on the page. Only 2 on about 15 do it.

Comment: Changed doctype to HTML 4.01 Strict. Didn't fix it.